# XAML DataTrigger ignoring INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

The style below controls the background colour for rows in a GridControl. The row viewmodel has a boolean property "IsYellow", if this is true the background should be yellow. I also want the selected row to be grey.

```
<Style>  
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsYellow}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsYellow}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I know the style is working because rows are correctly shown as yellow or white on startup and are grey when selected (going back to their previous colour when the selection moves)

When IsYellow changes, the DataTrigger doesn't seem to get notified of this. IsSelected continues to work, with the row going back to its original colour afterwards.

I know that INotifyPropertyChanged is working because IsYellow is also a column in the GridControl and always shows the correct value. (If I comment out the OnPropertyChanged("IsYellow") the column stops updating when they change)

Comment: Have you tried specifically adding to the Binding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` ?

Comment: @Damascus yes I've tried `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and also every option for `Mode=`

Comment: The solution is simple then: your `Background` is defined by your `IsSelected` trigger being the last one applied. Even if the previous are applied, it will then check if `IsSelected` is true or not. You should rather use a `MultiBinding` with a custom converter to figure out what to do with the two properties as an input

Comment: @Damascus no, because when `IsSelected=False` (i.e. after navigating away from the row) the other triggers are used, with stale data in `DataContext.IsYellow`

Comment: You'll have to put together a [*complete, but concise* working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly demonstrates your problem and edit your question with it.